How can I revoke a user's ability to generate oAuth tokens for a connected Auth. Provider?
I configured Google Drive as an Auth. Provider to use with Files Connect on a Per User Basis through an External Data Source.
When a user connects their Google Account through the file picker in Chatter or Files it creates an ExternalDataUserAuthentication record

I am trying to piggy back off of this connection to call Google APIs through the use of Auth.AuthToken.getAccessToken
@AuraEnabled
public static String generateGoogleOAuthToken() {
    AuthProvider google = [SELECT Id, ProviderType FROM AuthProvider WHERE DeveloperName = 'Google_Drive'];
    String providerName = 'Open ID Connect';
    String token = Auth.AuthToken.getAccessToken(google.Id, providerName);
    return token;
}

This works after the user navigates to the OAuth-Only Initialization URL which Salesforce provides on the AuthProvider.OauthKickoffUrl field for the Auth. Provider record.
@AuraEnabled
public static AuthorizeUrls getGoogleDriveAuthorizeUrls() {
    AuthProvider google = [
        SELECT Id, AuthorizeUrl, OauthKickoffUrl
        FROM AuthProvider
        WHERE DeveloperName = 'Google_Drive'
    ];
    return new AuthorizeUrls(google.AuthorizeUrl, google.OauthKickoffUrl);
}

However, when I delete the user's ExternalDataUserAuthentication record they can't access google drive through chatter without reconnecting their account (which is expected) but they can still successfully generate an oauth token through my apex method(which is unexpected).
How can I revoke the user's ability to generate an oauth token?

they can still successfully generate an oauth token through my apex method(which is unexpected). - what is your expectation (or lack thereof) based on?

@identigral It's my expectation that if the User's ExternalDataUserAuthentication is deleted they are unable to receive an OAuthToken through the Auth.AuthToken.getAccessToken method. So I am asking what do I need to do to make that so? What am I missing to revoke the user's access?

OAuth-Only Initialization URL will trigger a generation of a fresh token, if one doesn't exist. This is expected. To remove the user's access to target resource (Google Drive), you either prevent them from accessing the auth provider (how you do this depends on your solution architecture) or remove their access at Google Drive side. The latter is recommended.

@identigral It looks like if the user navigates to the Single Logout URL from the Auth. Provider it revokes the ability to generate more oauth tokens which is what I need

Single Logout merely terminates the session, it'll probably revoke the current token. If it appears to prevent the ability to generate fresh tokens, that would be unexpected - a bug on SF side and/or a side effect of how Google Drive behaves.
